# Как итерироваться по полям массива структуры? (С#)

Tags: c#, массивы

Существует определённая структура:

```
public struct Ok
        {
            public string name;
            public string surname;
            public string lastname;
            public string gender;
            public string nationality;
            public DateTime date_of_birth;
            public string number;
            public string address;
            public float pension;
        }
```

Каким образом можно проитерироваться по полю pension и найти минимальное значение, записанное в массив структуры? (arr)

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp24
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Ok
        {
            public string name;
            public string surname;
            public string lastname;
            public string gender;
            public string nationality;
            public DateTime date_of_birth;
            public string number;
            public string address;
            public float pension;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ok[] arr = new Ok[0];
            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Хотите ли вы добавить человека в реестр(+/-)?: ");
                string a = Console.ReadLine();
                if (a == "+")
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length + 1);
                    Console.Write("Введите имя: ");
                    arr[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите фамилию: ");
                    arr[i].surname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите отчество: ");
                    arr[i].lastname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите пол: ");
                    arr[i].gender = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите национальность: ");
                    arr[i].nationality = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите дату рождения: ");
                    arr[i].date_of_birth = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Введите номер: ");
                    arr[i].number = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите адрес: ");
                    arr[i].address = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите количество лет на пенсии: ");
                    arr[i].pension = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            int numb = 0;
            float min = arr[0].pension;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Пенсионеры которые на пенсии больше 5 лет: ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (min > arr[i].pension)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].name);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].surname);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].lastname);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].gender);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].nationality);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].date_of_birth);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].number);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].address);
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].pension);
                    min = arr[i].pension;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может я конечно чего-то не понимаю, но вроде это вы и делаете в приведенном коде...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (arr.Length > 0) {
  int iMinPension = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].pension < arr[iMinPension].pension)
      iMinPension = i;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("person with the smallest pension:");
  Console.WriteLine(arr[iMinPension].name);
  Console.WriteLine(arr[iMinPension].pension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ok minOk = arr.SortBy(item => item.pension).First();
```